# Mac Mini CRT support

Tags: mac, resolution, vga, crt

I have two 1600 x 1200 VGA CRTs. I've tried hooking them up to my Late 2014 Mac Mini, but the native resolution is not detected on either of them. One will not go higher than 1280 x 1024. Is there a way I can force the resolution to what my 4:3 monitor supports?

Answer (score 0):

Lookup the mac app SwitchResX - Most resolution issues are rectified with this.

Comment: Please read [how to recommend software in answers](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers), particularly the bits in **bold**; then edit your answer to follow the guidelines there. Thanks!